# Is there a way preview selected image before uploading in IE?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The problem is that IE does not support javascripts Filereader. I thought about sending the file via ajax to the server, which then would echo back the files content. Could it be done this way? I have little experience with dynamic web development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without the File API, so the short answer is no.

Longer answer is that that would require access to files on the client computer which is outside of the reach of JavaScript, or access to the data in memory before being transferred.  The latter is provided in the HTML5 File API, but the two are impassable boundaries in earlier versions due to functional and security restrictions.

The backwards compatible option is to provide a staging area on the server (possibly just in memory) so the file is previewed after initial upload but before being persisted.